# Menu permission/visibility control

Tags: 7, routes, users, aegir

I am in involved in developing a site builder using Drupal 7.  Since it is a site builder, I need a user to be able to create menu items based on their needs, and then edit those menu items - but not any other users.

Also, is it possible to create a sub-domain during sign-up (along the lines of Drupal Gardens)?

Comment: You have two completely separate questions in there, please avoid that. One question per question.

Answer (score 1):

For the Drupal Garden's style setup, you should definitely look at [Aegir](http://www.aegirproject.org/).  It requires a bit of setting up, but there are loads of tutorials and screncasts - there are a couple of good ones [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Rf_E4dl4zk) and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fk6HaXnPMrM).

With regards to your menu question, that seems like a simple permissions question.  When you deploy your new sites, you'll obviously have to set up a user for the owner of said site.  If you ensure that user has a particular user role, you can set permissions at "/admin/people/permissions" for the core menu module.  Look under Menu around halfway down the page and check the box for `Administer menus and menu items` for your site owner's user role.

Comment: thanks for giving valuable suggestion.i install Aegir in my local system(ubuntu11.10) successfully in automated way.While i trying to install VPS same environment i got "package not found" During  issue following  command "apt-get install aegir" i update repository  also but still get same error.Is there any thing Need to perform specially for VPS.